# Excel SUM value from TextBox

Tags: excel, textbox

How to get value from textbox in excel. I have 3 textbox, TextBox 1, TextBox 2, TextBox 3. How to SUM all three textbox to cell "A4". When I update textbox, the cell "A4" is change.

Answer (score 0):

Bear in mind that text boxes contain text (strings), even in their `Value` property. Therefore their value must be converted to a number when summing up and the resulting number must be converted to text when it's assigned to TextBox4. Most of this VBA will do automatically most of the time. If you want your program to work correctly **all** the time you should consider giving instructions. The following code will create a value that can be assigned to a variable of Double data type.

```
Dim MySum As Double
MySum = Val(TextBox1.Value) + Val(TextBox2.Value) + Val(TextBox3.Value)
```

This Double can be assigned directly to a worksheet cell.

```
Cells(4, "A").Value = MySum
```

Be mindful that Cells(4, "A").Value = TextBox1.Value may not have the same effect because in one case a number is assigned, in the other a string.

In order to update Range("A4") when one of the text boxes changes value you should use the TextBox's `BeforeUpdate` event. The `Change` event fires whenever you type a character which will give you a lot of flicker because updates are run before the user finishes typing. With the Before or `AfterUpdate` events the updating of worksheet cell will occur when the text box being changed loses the focus.

Comment: I don't want update the result to TextBox, but to the excel cell, any cell, like cell "A4"

Comment: Aah, yes. I modified my answer. Sorry about that.

Comment: Can you write the complete code, because I am very new about excel VBA. I can't get you.

Comment: The snippets above are about as "complete" as they can be made, given that you haven't told us anything about the environment, such as whether your text boxes are on a user form or worksheet. But that wasn't necessary because neither this forum, nor I, wish to offer free code-writing. So, I'm afraid you will be on your own. Take the parts, put them together, and, if help is still required, ask another question once you have done that.